# dreamweaver cc/cs6 database server extension doesn't connect

Tags: sql-server, database, asp-classic, dreamweaver

I've just installed the database server extension in dreamweaver cc and cs6. i have an existing site running classic ASP in dozens of pages built with previous DW versions all connected to SQL Server and working fine.

but now adobe has deprecated its server functionality and to get it back you must install that functionality with a free extension they have provided.

unfortunately when, after installing the extension, i open an ASP page and look into the Databases or Server Behaviors windows I can see the database names but there are no tables visible at all.

I've followed the steps in Adobe's help video at http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cB2vmNfcq7A and followed suggestions in numerous forums and blogs but cannot find a way to connect to the database once the extensions are installed.

Comment: Dreamweaver generated ASP code is very bloated.  It's quite easy to hand code your connection. Here's a short tutorial which covers the basics. 's http://webcheatsheet.com/asp/database_connection_to_MSSQL.php.  It's an old tutorial, you're better off using an oledb or native client connection string - see here - http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Comment: Well thanks for the links, I'll check them out. But I'd still very much like to know how to get Dreamweaver's functionality back.

Comment: I have cs6 and I can connect to SQL Server. You should have a folder at root level called Connections, containing files with DW generated connection strings.  Could you post the contents of the relevant one. (obviously you need to change username and password beforehand)

Comment: Yes I have the connections folder containing strings that work in that they operate with the db on the server. It's just that dreamweaver itself cannot see the tables in the db. I am trying to get the sites with db content operating on a new Mac.

Comment: Ah. I wasn't really expecting anyone to be doing Classic ASP/Sql Server development on a Mac. I'm running Win 7 Pro  You've probably tried this already, but DW gives you the choice of using drivers on your local machine or on the testing server when you set up a database connection.  Obviously you need to go for the testing server option as you won't find ODBC or OLEDB drivers on a Mac.  Other than this I don't know what else to suggest

Comment: Yes, I'm on a mac and have been developing this site on a mac in dreamweaver for over 10 years now. Lots of pages all having worked within DW until now. Now that server behaviors, db, etc are deprecated in CC/CS6 by Adobe there's a workaround extension that reinstalls the menu items, windows, et al, but does not connect DW to the database itself. No data. That's my problem

Comment: You might like to read this thread on the Adobe forum, although I'm afraid it only confirms that others have the same problem and offers no solutions. http://blogs.adobe.com/dreamweaver/2013/06/a-look-at-the-modernized-dreamweaver-cc.html.  Adobe have been slowly ditching Server Behaviours since they acquired DW.  JSP and ASP.net support was dropped with CS4, then Classic ASP with javascript with CS6